# Vue.js: How to initially check one of the radio button?

Tags: vue.js

I am using the following code to generate radio buttons in my template.

```vue
<template v-for="(property,index) in propertiesList">
    <input type="radio"  :value="index" v-model="picked2" 
     :checked="property.checked">{{property.address}}<br>
</template>
```

`property.checked` has value of `checked` for one of the rows, and is `null` for rest of rows. I want to show the corresponding row (with `property.checked = 'checked'`) as checked when the page is rendered. However, all rows appear as unchecked. Could someone please advise how to fix the issue? Thanks.

Comment: This is the [typical approach](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/pKJrgo?editors=1010). If you use v-model, let Vue manage which input is checked.

Comment: That works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user761100 mark question as answered please

Comment: @MaxLyashuk it doesn't work like that. Somebody would need to provide an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bret has provided the answer in the comment (to my question).